# Background iCloud processing slowing gui and corrupting view controller stack- how to stop multiple touches

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, icloud

I'm getting updates occasionally from NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification's. These are running in background asynch threads, but still slow down the app once in a while.

The problem is that this slows down my TableView enough so that if you click a row, it sometimes doesn't push it right away. It's a simple call inside tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
[detailViewController release];
```

If you touch the row a couple times (in frustration), the app viewcontroller stack gets messed up:

```
nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <DetailViewController: 0xdabc0c0>
```

How do I stop this from happening and only accept the first touch on the row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this partially for now. I tried to use:

```
[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

in my add button method and tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath but it didn't fix the multiple press issue. So I had to disable them individually:

creation of add button:

```
    UIBarButtonItem *bbi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addNew:)];
    self.addBtn = bbi;
    [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:bbi];
```

at the beginning of my addNew: method

```
[self.addBtn setEnabled:NO];
```

at the beginning of my tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

```
[self.myTable setAllowsSelection:NO];
```

in viewWillAppear:

```
[self.addBtn setEnabled:YES];
[self.myTable setAllowsSelection:YES];
```